# How to get data from property nested in Component with paramMap in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

Maybe I got blind, but I am working on this for some time now...

I try to get an id from a json-File delivered from an Observer:

`index.ts`

```
import {Provider} from "@angular/core";
import {_StaticBlogService, BlogService} from "./blog.service";

export const SHARED_SERVICES: Provider[] = [
  { provide: BlogService, useClass: _StaticBlogService }
];
```

`blog.service.ts`

```
export interface BlogEntry extends IBasics {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  category: Category;
}

export abstract class BlogService {
  abstract getAll(): Observable<BlogEntry[]>;
  abstract getById(blogEntryId: number): Observable<BlogEntry>;
}

@Injectable()
export class _StaticBlogService implements BlogService {

  url = '/data/blogeintraege.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAll(): Observable<BlogEntry[]> {
    return this.http.get<BlogEntry[]>(this.url);
  }

  getById(blogEntryId: number): Observable<BlogEntry> {
    return this.http.get<BlogEntry[]>(this.url).pipe(
      map(blogEntries => <BlogEntry>blogEntries.find(p => p.id === blogEntryId)));
  }
}
```

`blog.component.ts`

```
export class BlogComponent {
  blogEntry$: Observable<BlogEntry>;
  suggestedBlogEntries$: Observable<BlogEntry[]>;

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _blogService: BlogService) {
    this.blogEntry$ = this._route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        map(params => parseInt(params.get('blogEntryId') || '', 10)),
        filter(blogEntryId => Boolean(blogEntryId)),
        switchMap(blogEntryId => this._blogService.getById(blogEntryId))
      );
```

`app.routing.ts`

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
  { path: 'blogeintraege/:blogEntryId', loadChildren: './blog/blog.module#BlogModule' },
  { path: 'ausgaben/:ausgabeId', loadChildren: './ausgabe/ausgabe.module#AusgabeModule' }
];
```

but I don't get it to have an `id` from the json-File - and I think, this is because I get a `BlogComponent` as object (and its params) and not the "nested" property `BlogEntry` which may have the `id`-property:

[image: Debugging with Intellij IDEA (1)]

[image: Debugging with Intellij IDEA (2)]

[image: Debug Chrome Inspector]

Maybe some Angular Pro will see my misinterpretation on how to do it at first glance and can point me to an example?

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/Mesqualito/subjektiv-ng)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is that in routing file, param is set to `blogEntryId`, but in component you are trying to reach `blockEntryId` ?

Comment: That was a good one :-) Must have happened because of coding around my problem for hours. But unfortunately did not solve not getting an id. Thanks; I will update my code in the question and additionally paste Chrome Inspector output.